# AppDelegate's property not accessible

Tags: objective-c

I create a property `countryNameInitials` as NSMutableArray in AppDelegate.m interface and synthesize it. The purpose is to store global data to display in table view.  In the table view controller:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
...

@implementation
#define AppDelegate [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
...
```

The problem is that I cannot use `AppDelegate.countryNameInitials` to access the data. Any idea?

Comment: This is probably a naming conflict. Your #define has the same name as the AppDelegate class. Try changing your #define to another name.

Comment: Good thought. Yet I tried other names and still don't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of accessing `countryNameInitials` is due to I declared the property in AppDelegate.m. After I move it to AppDelegate.h, errors are gone.

Side notes:
1. `AppDelegate` as the identifier name works for me. Naming conflicts suggested by @Vakio is not relevant.

Answer (score 3):

The fact is that

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```

will give you a generic `UIApplcationDelegate`; while you need your `MyOwnAppDelegate` (don't know how you called it) type to be able to use your `countryNameInitials` property. So, try with:

```
 #define AppDelegate ((MyOwnAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])
```

then

```
AppDelegate.countryNameInitials
```

should work.

(I would not use the same name for the class and the macro, though).

Comment: I copy paste your #define line yet get an error "missing '[' at start of message send expression"

Comment: can you paste the line where you get the error? that syntax is working for me for property dereferencing...

Comment: `#define AppDelegate ((TableWithIndexingAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])`

Comment: it seems strange to me that the `#define` itself produces the error... I can paste it in any project of mine and it compiles...